# How do I develop a JDBC application to take data from a keyboard and store it in a database?

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I develop a JDBC application to take data from a keyboard and store it in a database? Do we need to separate business logic and presentation logic?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow please take a look at how to ask a question section. And about your question maybe you should take a look at MVC pattern (model-view-controller) which should fit to your project

Comment: Hi @Dheeraj Singh. Your question is too broad. You should show what you have tried and what is the issue. Regarding the seperation of business-presentation logic, this is up to you to follow n-tier vs monolithic application design, you can read/research on the pros and cons between each application design and architecture.

Comment: i need code...please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do a standalone java application then you do not need presentation layer. The input could be obtained from "keyboard" using Scanner library. But if you are talking about a web application then you need use any framework preferably spring to create a Model, View, Controller (MVC) application.